# Kotlin lambda function with only return statement

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I am struggling with a warning that I don't understand what it means. Please help me to understand and resolve this. However it suggested to use labeled return that I don't want to use because it kind of looks ugly to me. Is there any other way around?

[image: Warning with lambda return]

Comment: That's a warning from your IDE. What IDE are you using? Is that IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes it is Intellij.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a function that takes a lambda parameter, like `let`:

```
user?.let { it.name }
```

You can do this same operation with a property reference instead of a lambda:

```
user?.let(User::name)
```

---

Apparently - since this IntelliJ inspection is in place - it's a somewhat common mistake to accidentally combine the two, and use a property reference *inside* curly braces instead of one or the other, like this:

```
user?.let { User::name }
```

... or like this:

```
user?.let { user::name }
```

These would result in getting that property reference as the returned value instead of the name that you might've expected.

Comment: So I should not use property references inside lambda? or I need to apply parenthesis to make this warning go away. I'm doing this because I need the property reference(KProperty<*>) to look up values from a map to validate.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use them inside a lambda if you know that that's what you need. This lint warning is there to prevent people from doing it by accident.